# VBA: Why does correct dictionary value only get added after a MsgBox is triggered?

Tags: excel, vba, dictionary

I have come across a particular quirk in VBA and I'm not sure of a permanent fix. A value only gets added to my dictionary when a MsgBox is triggered. I'm expecting 12345 to get added to my dictionary. However i the first example below, it does not.

```
For i = 2 To lastrow
    If (Not today.exists(.Cells(i, headers.Item("SL_ID")).Value) And _
       .Cells(i, headers.Item("Assigned Date")).Value >= Date - minusDays And _
       Len(.Cells(i, headers.Item("Assigned Status")).Value) > 3 And _
       InStr(LCase(.Cells(i, headers.Item("Assigned Status")).Value), "started") = 0) Then
           today.Add Key:=.Cells(i, headers.Item("SL_ID")).Value, _
            Item:=Array(.Cells(i, headers.Item("Assigned Status")).Value, _
                        .Cells(i, headers.Item("Completion Date")).Value, _
                        .Cells(i, headers.Item("On Hold Comments")).Value, _
                        "-", "-", "-", "-", "Rework", source)
    End If
Next i
```

But the following code with the MsgBox does in fact work as expected and 12345 is added to my dictionary.

```
For i = 2 To lastrow
    If (.Cells(i, headers.Item("SL_ID")).Value = "12345") Then
        MsgBox ("Wow, it's 12345")
    End If

    If (Not today.exists(.Cells(i, headers.Item("SL_ID")).Value) And _
       .Cells(i, headers.Item("Assigned Date")).Value >= Date - minusDays And _
        Len(.Cells(i, headers.Item("Assigned Status")).Value) > 3 And _
        InStr(LCase(.Cells(i, headers.Item("Assigned Status")).Value), "started") = 0) Then
                today.Add Key:=.Cells(i, headers.Item("SL_ID")).Value, Item:=Array(.Cells(i, headers.Item("Assigned Status")).Value, .Cells(i, headers.Item("Completion Date")).Value, .Cells(i, headers.Item("On Hold Comments")).Value, "-", "-", "-", "-", "Rework", source)
    End If
Next i
```

Does anyone have an idea to why this is? Is the pause of opening the MsgBox allowing Excel to "catch up" and add it correctly? Is this a known issue?

Any help is appreciated. Obviously my solution is not a permanent fix, and I'm keen to understand why such a strange thing would occur.

Comment: What comparemode is the dictionary set at? If you didn't set it when the dict was created, it should be vbBinaryCompare.

Comment: It is set to vbBinaryCompare. Still no luck.

Comment: Are there multiple *12345* values where the other conditions match? Are some 12345's text and others true numbers? Both 12345 as a true number and "12345" as text can be added to a dict's keys.

Comment: Nope. No value of 12345 is being added. Interestingly, I just did an analysis and any row with matching criteria after i = 3651 did not get added. If I add an if statement like:

    If(i = 3651) Then
        MsgBox(i)
    End If

It will continue through the loop as expected. Have you seen anything like this before?

Comment: There's something else you're not telling us.

Comment: Please do not call a dictionary today. Use something descriptive that is not a function name. Whilst not the problem it is good practice.

Comment: Showing some sample data (as an insert, not as a picture) and a picture of your data layout may help at this point.